# TVs oversize Apple TV game

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen, apple-tv, edges

We are working on a game using Unity 3D. And now we have a problem with Apple TV build: most of the TV's on which we tested the game use some kind of zoomed screen mode by default. And in our game the edges of the screen are important.

Is there a way to make a TV screen fit the image by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Screen.safeArea](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-safeArea.html) and position your game edges inside.

And if still necessary build a view where the user can adjust your game edges to his screen edges.